# Power Pivot / Power BI Handling Blanks in Power Pivot/PowerBI

Tags: pivot

I have a table, which is as under:

TABLE1

```
5670    Paid for A  1000    A   PK1
5670    Paid for B  200 B   PK2
5120    Paid for C  300     
5120    Paid for D  400     PK2
5120    Paid for E  500 E   PK2
5120    Paid for F  600 F
```

TABLE2

```
T1CODE  Name
A   Group A
B   Group B
E   Group E
F   Group F
```

The output from the above data:

```
Row Labels  Sum of Amount
(blank) 700
A   1000
B   200
E   500
F   600
Grand Total 3000
```

Required output using DAX:

```
Row Labels  Sum of Amount
A           1000
B           200
E           500
F           600
Grand Total 3000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sum Of Values =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'TABLE1'[Amount] ),
    FILTER ( 'TABLE1', 'TABLE1'[Row Labels] <> BLANK () )
)
```